# One to Optional One Relation not updating the Principal Entity on EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I Run into this scenario. I have related entities: **Case** and a **Confinement**

A Case has an optional navigation to confinement - ConfinementId, while the confinement has a required CaseId.

My problem is when I try to update the Case, by attaching the Confinement Record, the confinementID on the case entity is not updated.

Here are my mapping and Entity Classes:

```
public class Confinement : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Case Case {get;set;}
 }

public class Case : Entity
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseReferenceId { get; set; }
    public int? ConsultationId { get; set; }
    public int? ConfinementId { get; set; }
    public virtual Confinement Confinement { get; set; }
    ****Omitted
 }
```

**Configuration**

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Case> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.CaseId);
        builder.HasMany(t => t.Details)
            .WithOne(t => t.Case)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.CaseId);

        builder.HasOne(t => t.Confinement)
            .WithOne(a=>a.Case)
            .HasForeignKey<Confinement>(t => t.CaseId);
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Confinement> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        builder.HasOne(a => a.Case)
            .WithOne(a => a.Confinement)
            .HasForeignKey<Confinement>(a => a.CaseId);
    }
```

**Controller Code**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddConfinement(int caseId)
{
    if (caseId == 0)
        return BadRequest();
    if (_service.ExistingCase(caseId))
        return BadRequest("Case has already a confinement record!");
    var @case = await _caseService.FindAsync(caseId);
    if (@case == null)
        return NotFound("Case not found!");
    var confinement = _converter.ConvertFromCase(@case);
    confinement.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
    @case.Confinement = confinement;
    @case.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;
    @case.ConfinementId = confinement.Id;
    _caseService.Update(@case);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

When the AddConfinement Method is called, the confinement is added on the database, but the Case.ConfinementId is not updated. Is there anything wrong to this implementation.
As a workaround, I created a trigger on the database but i want to accomplish this on the application level.

Comment: `Case.ConfinementId` is redundant and basically unused. Only dependent entities have FK.

Comment: That's what i realized if removed the ConfinementId on the case, how will I be able to get the related Confinement from the case? Then the relationship can be made one-to-many? I want to preserve the one-to-one relationship

Comment: By using `Include`. Or in general, accessing the `case.Confinement` navigation property - in both LINQ to Entities queries or materialized `Case` object with navigation property loaded (lazy/eager/explicit). Nothing special.

Comment: Then create a composite key on the confinement to validate one to one relationship.. Hmmmm... sounds good.

Comment: @IvanStoev your idea worked! I also made the Id and caseId a composite key and then worked as expected.

Comment: Not sure why you need composite key. Removing `ConfinementId` from `Case` should be enough. Then you have 2 options for `Confinement` - either separate FK `CaseId` as currently, or remove it and use `Id` as both PK and FK (the so called "Shared Primary Key association"). Both models are supported by EF Core. For more info, see [Relationships - One-to-one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one) . Cheers.